# Different designed modals for flagging a question and comment

Tags: bug, design

Why does the design *(not the content<sup>1</sup>)* of the modal for flagging a question look different from that for a comment?

Flag modal for question:

- This has hooked borders.
- The background color of the close button is black.
- It has a margin on the left and the right.
- Outside the modal is 100% transparant.
- It has gray radiobuttons

[image: flag modal for question]

Flag modal for comment:

- This has rounded borders.
- The background color of the close button is white.
- It has no margin on the left and the right.
- Outside the modal is semi-transparant.
- It has white radiobuttons.

[image: flag modal for comment]

<sup>1</sup> My question goes **not** about the content of the modal! It's just the look and feel of the modal.

Comment: probably because they are still mid-flight going from the "junk" they currently have to the new responsive [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks). Some bits are done, some not yet. Give it 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I am developer & there is no strong reason except choice of designer/developer. It does not denote anything remarkable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we [updated the comment flag reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct) back in July/August, the modal was moved over to the [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks) design (as rene guessed). We haven't needed to update the content of the post flags - or close modal on questions, or ... well, lots of other site elements - so they're still using the old styling.

It's probably just as well that we didn't update them all, since the initial implementation was missing [at least one popular feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313631/make-the-comment-flag-dialog-draggable-again?r=SearchResults&s=40%7C0.0000) - which we've now added back in.

We'll be updating these modals before long, sometime in the next 6-8. Thanks for your patience while we work through this transition!